# Ecommerce Purchase event, fire on seperate page

Tags: google-analytics

Before I explain the issue it's worth noting at the start I do not have access to any `html` or `server side code`.

I'm tagging a website for a client, their website is some what similar to an ecommerce platform, there are 3 stages the user goes through before purchasing which are as follows:

1. Step 1 - Choose items from a table and click `add` button, then press submit which takes them to Step 2
2. Step 2 - User can modify the quantity of each product they have selected to purchase or remove the product once finished they press submit which takes them to step 3
3. Step 3 - On this page the user can only submit the order, once they've submitted they're taken to a confirmation page - saying thanks order received etc

The issue I'm experiencing and trying to solve is this:

I'm setting up an ecommerce purchase event, inside this event I'm trying to pass the transaction information, along with the product information.

The transaction / product information is only located on Step 3.  This event I'm setting up needs to fire on the confirmation page as this is when we know the submission has taken place and the order has been received.

I've gone through documentation around ecommerce events and I'm yet to find if any, anything that can help solve the issue.  I was hoping to find a solution whereby I can build the ecommerce event on Step 3 and on the confirmation page fire the event.  Any suggestions?

Comment: So you want to fire the event on the transaction success page, but have the product information from the step 3 of the funnel. Am I right? If yes, is there any information for the product details in the transaction complete page ?

Comment: @Igneel64 That's correct, the event needs to fire on the success page.  On the transaction page it does hold information about the products, however it's a cut down version of what was bought.  And the requirements are to track the complete product(s) / transaction info from Step 3.

Comment: Persisting data between pageviews will require some code (not necessarily server side code, but at least javascript and cookies or localstorage), so with your limitations you cannot solve this (on the other hand since you say you are tagging the website you must have some way of inserting client side code ?).

Comment: @EikePierstorff That is my thought exactly.

Comment: We do have access to client side code, but our access is very limited.  Now I did look into a cookie, but cookies have limits regarding how much they can store, and we found half of the data was being cut off when writing to the cookie due exceeding its size.  Also looked into LocalStorage, and I've been informed this will only work on certain browsers. So those two options unfortunately are not suitable.

Comment: What browsers do you want to support ? If you look at http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage you'll see that all current major browsers support this (except Opera Mini which isn't really a concern for most people).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would try to review the requirements, the average transaction product quantity and then decide to go with JavaScript client-side code(implemented from GTM) to store the required product data on a cookie or the localstorage. Be careful though these solutions come with many limitations.

Cookies on mobile devices have smaller size restrictions for example.

The best way in my opinion is to communicate with the server-side developers. Because by doing this in the frontend you are risking many inconsistencies with the real data. Frontend code introduces browser compatibility issues, turned-off javascript and many more.

Also until you find a more suitable approach, you can scrape the minimum required information for the products and transaction, directly from the order-complete page. This could be done with pure-js or jQuery if it is available.

Comment: Think I'll have to chat with the backend devs and see if we can come to some sort of arrangement.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @CodeRatchet Good call, If you require anything else depending on the answer you can comment here so I can edit my response